# "X11 libraries not found" error when installing the X11 package with Stack

Tags: haskell, x11, haskell-stack

I need to use the [x11 package](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.2/package/X11-1.8) with the [lts-8.2 resolver](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.2), and when I run the command `stack build`, I get the following :

```
X11-1.8: configure
Progress: 1/2
--  While building package X11-1.8 using:
/tmp/stack7885/X11-1.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0    /setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0 configure --with-ghc=/home/userXYZ/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/home/userXYZ/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/pkgdb --libdir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/lib --bindir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/bin --datadir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/share --libexecdir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/etc --docdir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/doc/X11-1.8 --htmldir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/doc/X11-1.8 --haddockdir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/doc/X11-1.8 --dependency=base=base-4.9.1.0 --dependency=data-default=data-default-0.7.1.1-7EGYJX2YWqWJRbPFUHNoCr

Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: /home/userXYZ/Documents/programming/haskell/projects/MyStack/screen-linux/.stack-work/logs/X11-1.8.log

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/stack7885/X11-1.8/Setup.hs, /tmp/stack7885/X11-1.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/Main.o )

/tmp/stack7885/X11-1.8/Setup.hs:6:29: warning: [-Wdeprecations]
    In the use of ‘defaultUserHooks’
    (imported from Distribution.Simple):
    Deprecated: "Use simpleUserHooks or autoconfUserHooks, unless you need Cabal-1.2
             compatibility in which case you must stick with defaultUserHooks"
Linking /tmp/stack7885/X11-1.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup ...
Warning: defaultUserHooks in Setup script is deprecated.
Configuring X11-1.8...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-hc
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /usr/bin/gcc -E
checking for X... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/stack7885/X11-1.8':
configure: error: X11 libraries not found, so X11 package cannot be built
See `config.log' for more details
```

I am running on LinuxMint 17.2 64bits.

I found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2735), but unfortunately that did not help me to solve my issue.

I am looking for any help to fix the issue. I am not entirely sure where to start with.

===============================

EDIT: following the suggestion of duplode, I loaded libx11-dev, and then got the following set of other messages after running `stack build` :

```
    X11-1.8: configure
Progress: 1/2
--  While building package X11-1.8 using:
    /tmp/stack12282/X11-1.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0 configure --with-ghc=/home/userXYZ/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/home/userXYZ/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/pkgdb --libdir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/lib --bindir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/bin --datadir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/share --libexecdir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/etc --docdir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/doc/X11-1.8 --htmldir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/doc/X11-1.8 --haddockdir=/home/userXYZ/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.2/8.0.2/doc/X11-1.8 --dependency=base=base-4.9.1.0 --dependency=data-default=data-default-0.7.1.1-7EGYJX2YWqWJRbPFUHNoCr
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: /home/userXYZ/Documents/programming/haskell/projects/MyStack/screen-linux/.stack-work/logs/X11-1.8.log

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/stack12282/X11-1.8/Setup.hs, /tmp/stack12282/X11-1.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/Main.o )

/tmp/stack12282/X11-1.8/Setup.hs:6:29: warning: [-Wdeprecations]
    In the use of ‘defaultUserHooks’
    (imported from Distribution.Simple):
    Deprecated: "Use simpleUserHooks or autoconfUserHooks, unless you need Cabal-1.2
             compatibility in which case you must stick with defaultUserHooks"
Linking /tmp/stack12282/X11-1.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup ...
Warning: defaultUserHooks in Setup script is deprecated.
Configuring X11-1.8...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-hc
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /usr/bin/gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /usr/bin/gcc -E
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking for remove... yes
checking for shmat... yes
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... no
checking whether to build Xinerama... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking X11/extensions/Xinerama.h usability... no
checking X11/extensions/Xinerama.h presence... no
checking for X11/extensions/Xinerama.h... no
WARNING: Xinerama headers not found. Building without Xinerama support
checking X11/extensions/Xrandr.h usability... no
checking X11/extensions/Xrandr.h presence... no
checking for X11/extensions/Xrandr.h... no
configure: error: X11/extensions/Xrandr.h (from libXrandr) is required
```

Comment: It seems you don't have the (non-Haskell) X11 development headers installed in your system. While I don't have Mint to test it, I suspect installing [*libx11-dev*](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libx11-dev) will solve the problem.

Comment: @duplode. Thank for your help. I am not sure how you found this, but I did load libx11-dev, but I got a new set of error messages, which I will add to the original post as an edit.

Comment: It is the same issue, except with other libraries. You have to install the Mint **-dev* packages that provide the headers for *Xrandr* and *Xinerama* (the libraries mentioned in the errors/warnings).

Comment: Thanks! As suggested I loaded [libx11-dev](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libx11-dev), [libxrandr-dev](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libxrandr-dev), [libxinerama-dev](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libxinerama-dev) and `stack build` did work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Errors about missing libraries when installing packages with *stack* or *cabal-install* are typically about non-Haskell dependencies that must be installed separately, as the Haskell-specific tools aren't meant to pull them on their own. In this case, to quote [the readme](https://github.com/xmonad/X11) of the *X11* Haskell package...

> You will need development versions of at least the X11, xrandr, and Xinerama libraries installed for the build to succeed [...]

The development versions of these libraries can be installed through the package manager of your Linux distribution; in the case of Mint they amount to the [*libx11-dev*](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libx11-dev), [*libxrandr-dev*](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libxrandr-dev) and [*libxinerama-dev*](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libxinerama-dev) packages respectively.